# Cucumber: Can't pass an integer value to a step

Tags: cucumber, gherkin

I have the following step:

```
When REST create 10 users prefixed with "user"
```

And I tried to define the steps like this:

The only working step definition is

```
@When("^REST create (*) users prefixed with \"(.*)\"$")
```

But obviously this matches everything and I'd like to pass only integers 1 and above.

All the next things I tried didn't work (weren't glued):

```
@When("^REST create (d+) users prefixed with \"(.*)\"$") 
@When("^REST create d+ users prefixed with \"(.*)\"$") 
@When("^REST create {int} users prefixed with \"(.*)\"$") 
@When("^REST create ([1-9]+[1-9]*) users prefixed with \"(.*)\"$") 
@When("^REST create [1-9]+[1-9]* users prefixed with \"(.*)\"$")
```

Why??? I can't understand the problem!

Cucumber version is 1.2.5. I know it is outdated, but I am a part of a large project in which currently we prefer to stay with this version.

Comment: @When("^REST create (\\d+) users prefixed with \"([^\"]*)\"$")
    public void restCreateUsersPrefixedWith(int arg0, String arg1)  {
        // Write code here that turns the phrase above into concrete actions
    }

Comment: In case you want to use the same step for providing a different number of users the gherkin step should be When REST create "10" users prefixed with "user"   and the correspondent step definition is @When("^REST create \"([^\"]*)\" users prefixed with \"([^\"]*)\"$")
    public void restCreateUsersPrefixedWith(String arg0, String arg1)  {
        // Write code here that turns the phrase above into concrete actions
    }

Comment: @MrCas Thank you so much. I understood the first solution and if you'll add it as an answer I'd happily accept it. But I didn't understand the rational of the second solution... What is the advantage of using the string instead of the int?

Comment: For ex if you have a scenario outline and you want to provide different value for each scenario:
 
Scenario Outline: Creation of users 
When REST create "number of users" users prefixed with "user"
Examples:            
  | number of users |
  | 10                       |
  | 100                     |
  | 1000                   |

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe you are looking for:

```
@When("^REST create (\\d+) users prefixed with \"([^\"]*)\"$")
public void restCreateUsersPrefixedWith(int arg0, String arg1) {
// Write code here that turns the phrase above into concrete actions 
}
```

And for ex if you have a scenario outline and you want to provide different value for each scenario:

```
Scenario Outline: Creation of users 
When REST create "number of users" users prefixed with "user"

Examples:

| number of users |

| 10              |

| 100             |

| 1000            |
```

Then the correspondent step definition will be:

```
@When("^REST create \"([^\"]*)\" users prefixed with \"([^\"]*)\"$")
public void restCreateUsersPrefixedWith(String arg0, String arg1)  {
    // Write code here that turns the phrase above into concrete actions
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue of an integer in my step definition not being glued. The failing step definition was trying to use `([^[0-9]]*)` to handle the number. But when I changed it to `([0-9])`, it worked. So, if you change your code to:

`@When("^REST create ([0-9]) users prefixed with \"(.*)\"$")`

...that should do the trick.